# Can some components of metric be Finslerian while the others be Riemannian?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

A [Finsler metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold) reduces to a Riemann metric in case it loses its dependence on velocities. Now, my question is this: Can we have a Finsler metric in which some components of the metric have velocity dependency and some do not?

These are components of a general Finsler metric tensor: $g_{\mu \nu}(x^\lambda, \dot{x}^\lambda)$, where $\dot{x}^\lambda = \frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}$ are the velocities and $\tau$ is a scalar parameter ($\mu$, $\nu = 0, 1, 2, 3$). Suppose I know that some specific components of the metric, say $g_{ij}$ ($i,j=1,2,3$), do not depend on $\dot{x}^\lambda$. Can I conclude that the other components, $g_{00}$ and $g_{0i}$, must also not depend on $\dot{x}^\lambda$ so that the metric becomes totally Riemannian? or those components can depend on $\dot{x}^\lambda$ regardless of the components $g_{ij}$?

Comment: Comments to the question (v2): 1. A direct product $M\times N$ of two Finsler manifolds $M$ and $N$ is again a Finsler manifold by adding the Finsler function $F_M+F_N$. 2. Comment #1 is in particular true if $N$ is a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: Thanks Qmechanic, Could you be more detailed about how that answers my question? I'm thinking about distinct components of the metric. My question actually is that if I know that some components of the metric do not have velocity dependency, Can I conclude that the metric is totally Riemannian or it can still be Finslerian?

Comment: Comments to the question (v2): Could you please clarify your definition of velocity in the context of a Finsler manifold? Are you restricting to just Randers manifolds?

Comment: I have edited the question.